# How to make unordered_map<string*, V> hash by value instead of reference?

Tags: c++, c++14

I have the following

[image: C++ code with unordered_map]

The two equivalent strings bar and bartest do not map to the same value in unordered_map. How can I make this happen?

Comment: Use `std::unordered_map<std::string, V>`.

Comment: In the future it would be better if you pasted the code here instead providing a snapshot.

Comment: `std::string`, besides being a string class, is also a resource managing class. So don't add superfluous overhead by making the string object itself a resource to manage. Use value semantics, like Pete Becker said.

Comment: Paste your code here, and check out [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Of course they don't map to the same value, `const string*` is a pointer type and since you call `new string` twice, you end up with two separate objects that don't have memory identity (the pointers are not equal).

What's worse, you leak both of them at the end of your program.

What's (arguably) worse still, owning raw pointers and naked `new` calls are considered harmful in modern c++.

Luckily it's all fixed with `unordered_map<string, int>` - no pointers required whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Your C++ is in fact "Java-- + C".

Remove all those silly pointers.

All you need is `unordered_map<string,int>` and use plain values instead of heap-allocated "`new`s"

just do

```
#include <unordered_map>
#inclide <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    unordered_map<string,int> mymap;
    mymap["bar"] = 5;
    mymap["bartest"] = 10;

    std::cout << mymap["bar"] << ' ' << mymap["bartest"] << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```